# Error Handling for Scipy.optimize.curve_fit inside of a multiprocess pool from the 'multiprocess' module

Tags: python-3.x, windows, curve-fitting, multiprocess

My goal is to parallelize a bunch of 1d gaussian fits on a bunch of columns in an image.  I've used the module multiprocess instead of multiprocessing because I couldn't figure out a way to pass arrays as the arguments of a function being pickled without it.  This now works fine.

However, as soon as I use curve_fit inside of the function being pickled (or, in this case, dilled...), I have problems. If I comment out the curve_fit section and simply return the initial guess parameters, this all works fine.  But I'm unable to handle curve_fit RuntimeError as I might when processing data in a for loop, as such:

```
                    try:
                        params, _ = curve_fit(gauss1d,x,a,p0=guess)
                        params[3]=np.abs(params[3])+0.5
                    except RuntimeError:
                        params = [1,1,1,1]
```

Instead, if the fit doesn't converge, pool throws this error:

File "blablabla\lib\site-packages\multiprocess\pool.py", line 771, in get
raise self._value

error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats.

ValueError: object too deep for desired array

Which is due to this little fella:
File "blablabla\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 423, in leastsq
retval = _minpack._lmdif(func, x0, args, full_output, ftol, xtol,
minpack.error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats.

I believe I'm hitting the max function evals and getting ValueError, but my except is no longer handling this inside the pool for whatever reason.  It's also possible I'm chasing a red herring.

Full code below.  Adding additional exceptions (such as ValueError) didn't change anything.  All input appreciated.

```
 def processframe(framey):
        import numpy as np
        import scipy.ndimage as nd
        from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
        sizey = framey.shape
        paramsy = np.zeros([sizey[1],4])
        columnsy = np.split(framey,sizey[1],axis=1)
        
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            import numpy as np
            def thefit(k):
                def gfit1d(a): #simple 1d gaussian fit.  Fast.  Effective.  Uses 1d gauss stats to set initial parameters
                    def gguess1d(a): #This assumes a single gaussian 1d distribution on approximately the scale of a bright image (0 to 255), and returns stats for a 1d distribution, using physics rules (width is 1/e^2 radius)
                        x=np.linspace(1,np.amax(a.shape),np.amax(a.shape),endpoint=True)
                        fata = nd.gaussian_filter1d(a,2)
                        GuessY0 = np.amin(a)
                        GuessA = np.amax(a)-GuessY0
                        X0A = np.amax(fata)
                        X0Y0 = np.amin(fata)
                        X0form = np.multiply(fata+X0Y0,(fata+X0Y0>(X0A+X0Y0)/3))
                        GuessX0 = np.sum(np.multiply(X0form,x))/(1+np.sum(X0form))
                        GuessSigma = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(np.multiply(x-GuessX0,np.multiply(a-GuessY0,a-GuessY0>2))))/(1+np.sum(np.multiply(a-GuessY0,a-GuessY0>2))))/4
                        solution=np.asarray([GuessY0, GuessA, GuessX0, GuessSigma])
                        return np.nan_to_num(np.real(solution.flatten()))

                    therange = np.amax(a)-np.amin(a)
                    size = np.amax(a.shape)
                    x=np.linspace(1,size,size,endpoint=True)
                    guess =np.nan_to_num(np.real( gguess1d(a))).flatten()
                   
                    def gauss1d(x,aa,bb,cc,dd):
                        return aa+bb*np.exp(-2*(x-cc)**2/(np.abs(dd)+0.5)**2)+2000*(cc<1)*(1-cc)**2+2000*(cc>size)*(cc-size)**2+2000*(np.abs(aa-bb)>3*therange)*(np.abs(aa-bb)-3*(therange)**2)
                    try:
                        params, _ = curve_fit(gauss1d,x,a,p0=guess)
                        params[3]=np.abs(params[3])+0.5
                    except RuntimeError:
                        params = [1,1,1,1]
                    return np.nan_to_num(np.real(np.asarray(params.flatten())))
                    """
                    return guess
                    """
                    
                global paramsyk
                class paramsyk: pass
                try:
                    paramsyk=gfit1d(k)
                except RuntimeError:
                    #print(curse())
                    paramsyk=np.array([1,1,1,1])
                return np.asarray(paramsyk.flatten())
           # multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')
           # q=multiprocess.Queue(columnsy)
            pool=multiprocess.Pool(2)
            paramsy = pool.map(lambda x: np.asarray(thefit(columnsy[x])).flatten(), range(sizey[1]))
            pool.close
            pool.join
        
        return np.transpose(np.stack(paramsy,axis=1))
```

Comment: This code occasionally works, and occasionally does not.  Sometimes it says numpy or thefit are not defined, sometimes it compiles to the point where it runs on good datasets.  Same exact code.  Rebooting spyder sometimes makes things work, or makes things not work.  I've run up against a large collection of strange bugs, in addition to my general ignorance on handling exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Any time the compiler was able to compile anything in

```
paramsy = pool.map(lambda x: np.asarray(thefit(columnsy[x])).flatten(), range(sizey[1]))
```

The successful compile was itself a bug.  All things in lambda need to be defined within lambda,

2. Passing complicated objects to a function such as thefit() can be accomplished with a manager, by running the pool over a list.

```
def processframefitmulti(framey):
        t=time.time()
        import numpy as np
        import scipy.ndimage as nd
        from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
        sizey = framey.shape
            if __name__ == '__main__':
                def thefit(k):
                    import warnings
                    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
                    import numpy as np
                    import scipy.ndimage as nd
                    kk=np.array(k).flatten()    #This step is critical to this implementation, as it turns the object from a list back into an np array
                    #do some stuff

            columnsy = np.split(framey,sizey[1],axis=1)
            pool=multiprocess.Pool(3)
            mange=multiprocess.Manager()
            dataset=mange.list(columnsy)
            paramsy=pool.map(thefit,dataset)
            pool.close
            pool.join
     return np.stack(paramsy)
```

3. Exceptions need to be handled within multiprocessing pools as

```
try:
    params, _ = curve_fit(gauss1d,x,a,p0=guess)
    params[3]=np.abs(params[3])+0.5
except Exception as e:
    params = [1,1,1,1]
```

except Exception as e: is critical within multithreaded applications to prevent the whole thing from grinding to a halt.